# Download files from website with many links

Tags: linux

I am trying to download files from https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB5736 I want to download both file1 and file2 (Only the FTP fastq) files recursively for all the samples . Please let me know how to do it in linux.

Thanks

Comment: This question is far too unspecific, and is on the same level as _How do I do stuff with a computer?_  How do you expect answerers to answer this?  For all they know, you are manually clicking on hyperlinks in Firefox.

Comment: look at `wget`, sorry can't be more helpful, but question lacks detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the links are as regular as they look, you can try this:

```
results=147
for ((i=0; i<147; i++)); do
    base=ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR445/
    ext=$((445410+i))
    suff=.fastq.gz
    for j in 1 2; do wget "${base}${ext}/${ext}/_${j}${suff}"; done
done
```

There is nothing recursive in this download as far as I can see. Link address inspection gives some hint:

```
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR445/ERR445410/ERR445410_1.fastq.gz
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR445/ERR445410/ERR445410_2.fastq.gz
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR445/ERR445411/ERR445411_1.fastq.gz
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR445/ERR445411/ERR445411_2.fastq.gz
```

So there should be only three parts that change between them:

```
ERR<nr>/ERR<nr>_<1 or 2>
```

The stepping for `ERR` is 1 and the result count is 147, which makes for a complete answer, assuming that's all in this story. So after you've finished all downloads, count new files and make sure you have 2 * 147 of them.

The download procedure can certainly be optimised. As it is above, there's one `wget` process started for each link. I'll leave the optimisation up to you, presenting here just the analysis and the basic solution.